# What are these numbers after "MM, Bowing and Rhythm"?

Tags: scales, rhythm, violin, bowing

[image]

This Scales practice schedule from violin masterclass has numbers after MM, Bowing and Rhythm means. What do they mean?

Comment: Does looking up "Sassmannshaus" (as found in the header of your picture) yield anything?

Comment: @Dekkadeci I'm sure it will.  Wish we could teach people to go to the source before posting.   My guess is "bowing 2+2" is number of notes per bow direction and "Rhythm 2-4-6" either means "repeat three times, with X notes per beat," or it means "play 2 eighths,  four sixteenths, and a sextuplet," although the latter hardly fits into an 8-note scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture shows the MM indication several times,

first time MM=52

then a series of MM= without a number

later on MM=40

and finalley MM= without a number

MM indicates the metronome speed. So for the options without a number you probably decide the speed yourself. I can't think of any other meaning of MM in this context.

As far as I know MM is an abreviation of Maelzel's Metronome, since Maelzel is the inventor. There have been other attempts in the past, trying to make a device that would indicate the time, like using a pendul. Reference: [Metronome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metronome)

ELABORATION:

@CarlWitthoft wrote this comment:

> The MM is straightforward. IT's the others that require checking the Introduction to the studies.

Oh I see I have misunderstood the question. Well, after that misunderstanding I decided to go the violinmasterclass website to see what it is all about. After looking around on the site I will say this to @Mony who asked the question:
If you go to the website and click on "Video Tutorials" and then click on "Scales, Arpeggios, and Double Stops" you end up at this place: 
[Scales, Arpeggios, and Double Stops](https://www.violinmasterclass.com/posts/151)
Here I suggest you watch the videos under the section "Scales". Maybe those videos will give an idea on what the numbers mean. If not you could click on "Contact Us" under "About Us" and simply ask.

[image: Video on Scales]

Comment: The MM is straightforward.  IT's the others that require checking the Introduction to the studies.

Comment: Metronome Mark?

Comment: You are right @CarlWitthoft, so i have made an elaboration to my answer.